# How to set wpf control into multiple pages of pdf?

Tags: wpf, view, pdf-generation, export-to-pdf

[image: Here]
I've done a listview in wpf, it does perfectly in wpf but when I export my window into pages of pdf, listview is too long and it can't seperate into multiple pages.How can i solve this?

[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnOsl.png) is my output in pdf,the page2 listview can't show all of the content due to its size is bigger than A4 size.

Here is my code for exporting my view into pdf:

```
Grid Content;
    UIElement Child;
    UIElement Child2;
    public bool dialogresult;
    int Pgs;

    public void Subject(Grid content, UIElement child, UIElement child2, int pages)
    {
        Content = content;
        Child = child;
        Child2 = child2;
        Pgs = pages;
    }

    public void Printing()
    {


        #region 2pgs
        if (Pgs == 2)
        {
            var dialog = new SaveFileDialog();
            dialog.AddExtension = true;
            dialog.DefaultExt = "pdf";
            dialog.Filter = "PDF Document (*.pdf)|*.pdf";
            //dialog.ShowDialog();
            if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
            {
                dialogresult = true;
                PrintDialog printDialog = new PrintDialog();
                FixedDocument fixedDoc = new FixedDocument();
                PageContent pageContent = new PageContent();
                FixedPage fixedPage = new FixedPage();
                PrintDialog printDlg = new PrintDialog();
                Size pageSize = new Size(printDialog.PrintableAreaWidth, printDialog.PrintableAreaHeight);
                PrintCapabilities capabilities = printDialog.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(printDialog.PrintTicket);
                Size visibleSize = new Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);

                //var visual = Child as UIElement;
                (Content).Children.Remove(Child);
                fixedPage.Children.Add(Child);
                ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);
                fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent);

                FixedPage fixedPage1 = new FixedPage();
                PageContent pageContent1 = new PageContent();
                //var visual2 = Child2 as UIElement;
                (Content).Children.Remove(Child2);
                fixedPage1.Children.Add(Child2);
                ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent1).AddChild(fixedPage1);
                fixedDoc.Pages.Add(pageContent1);

                //write to PDF file
                string tempFilename = "temp.Xps";
                File.Delete(tempFilename);
                XpsDocument xpsd = new XpsDocument(tempFilename, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                XpsDocumentWriter xw = XpsDocument.CreateXpsDocumentWriter(xpsd);
                xw.Write(fixedDoc);
                xpsd.Close();
                PdfSharp.Xps.XpsConverter.Convert(tempFilename, dialog.FileName, 1);}
}
}
```

Please Help thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One Way to do it is scaling your controls and fixedPage to A4 size, before adding to document, don't forget to multiply with WPF rendering dpi

```
private double Dpi = 96;
private const double A4_WIDTH = 8.29;
private const double A4_HEIGHT = 11.69;

    public void Printing()
        {
    child.Width = A4_WIDTH *Dpi;
    child.Height = A4_HEIGHT *Dpi;

    //Your code

     fixedPage.Width = A4_WIDTH * Dpi;
     fixedPage.Height = A4_HEIGHT * Dpi;
...

     fixedPage.Children.Add(child);

    }
```

Comment: Hi, @Dark Knight thanks for your help, I met a problem on the Child.Width and Height..the error showing that my Child(UI Element does not contain a definition of Width and Height). How can I solve this? thanks in advance

Comment: I had child as UserControl instead of UIElement, if possible you can make it FrameWorkElement/UserControl and use actual Width and Height properties

Comment: I've changed my UIElement to FrameworkElement, but it seems to just changing the size of the view but it still does not show all of my list view item. Now my listview have 180 items but the pdf only show until 50th item

Comment: Oh, all 180 items visible in the view without scroll?

Comment: OK, my view is a bit different, I'm using a usercontrol to design a chart and a listview and locate in my window scrollviewer.Content. My listview's Height is auto so that my listview will not display the scrollbar. And now, im going to print the listview that come from my usercontrol,its 180 items but my pdf only display a part of it

Comment: I've edit my post the listview on my question above.U may refer.Thanks for help

Comment: Hi @Dark Knight,sorry for disturbing, can i convert my listview itemsSource directly into xps and convert it into PDF? How should I code it?

Comment: yes I am, previously I'm doing it with inserting the view and it will meet the problem as i mentioned above, so i think can i use the list<object> directly convert it into pdf.